# Nested Loops in ASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nested-loops

I'm given the following data:

```
DAYS = 7     ; constant representing the number of days in a week
HOURS = 24   ; constant representing the number of hours in a day
MINUTES = 60  ; constant representing the number of minutes in an hour
SECONDS = 60  ; constant representing the number of seconds in a minute

.data

date_time DWORD ? ; byte 0000 stores the DAY, byte 0001 stores the HOUR, 
byte 0002 stores the MINUTE, and byte 0003 stores the SECOND
num_of_iters DWORD 0  ; counts the total number of iterations
day BYTE DAYS   ; used to restore cl to the current day value
hour BYTE HOURS  ; used to restore cl to the current hour value
minute BYTE MINUTES  ; used to restore cl to the current minute value
```

The date_time variable should store 604,800 values one by one. Can someone show me how I 
would start the nested loops that are needed for this program? Thanks

Comment: You can use different registers for different counters, just like you'd use different named variables in C .  You don't need to do everything with saving/restoring `cl`.

Answer (score 2):

A loop in x86 could look like this:

```
mov <any register>, <start_value>
l_back:
   ...
   <do something>
   ...
inc <any register>
cmp <any register>, <end_value>
jbe l_back
```

What it does is simple: load *any register* with the starting value, and repeats  for all values up to (including)

What register you use is up to you, EAX, EBX, ECX, ... or even AH, AL, BH, BL if your range is in 0..255.

Nesting them is as easy, just take a new loop, and put it into "< do something >" ( the loop's body ) of the outer loop:

```
mov <any register>, <start_value>
l_back1:
   ...
    mov <any other register>, <other_start_value>
    l_back2:
       ...
       <do something nested>
       ...
    inc <any other register>
    cmp <any other register>, <other_end_value>
    jbe l_back2
   ...
inc <any register>
cmp <any register>, <end_value>
jbe l_back1
```

Things to keep in mind: If you clobber the control variables, the loops will not work. So either make sure you're NOT using them inside "< do something >", or store them before you enter the body, and restore them when you leave.

Sample:

```
mov ah, 0
   l1: mov al, 0
     l2: < put the body here >
   inc al
   cmp al, 60
   jbe l2
inc ah
cmp ah, 24
jbe l1
```